# gitlab-ci.yaml execute shell script

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have this script

```
echo builing deployme for branch $SourceBranch

rm -Rf project1
rm -Rf project2

git clone ssh://git@gitlab.yyy.com:2222/xxx/project1.git
cd  project1
mvn --settings .m2/settings.xml clean package

cd ..

git clone ssh://git@gitlab.yyy.com:2222/xxx/project2.git
cd  project2
mvn --settings .m2/settings.xml clean package
```

which is working in Jenkins.

Is there an easy/fast way to execute this in GitLab CI for some testing the process? Thx!

Comment: Short and basic answer would be to use a Gitlab Runner configured with a shell executor: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html
Depending on what your script is actually aiming at, you might just want to rethink it.